# Unity Animation on Button Click returns to Idle animation

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation, button, onclick

I have four buttons to select range of numbers. (clicked button should animate and stay scaled just to indicate which  button is selected) I am trying to play animation on button click in unity. so when button is clicked, animation is played and returns to idle. But I do not want it to return to idle state instead I want it to remain at the last frame of on click animation clip(at last frame scale is 1.2). Loop time is unchecked.
I have assigned onclick animator play(string) in the inspector. Please help
also tried following code

```
public GameObject rangeBtn;
public Animator rangeBtnAnim;   

private void Start()
{
    if ((rangeBtn != null) && (rangeBtn.GetComponent<Animator>() != null))
    {
        rangeBtnAnim = rangeBtn.GetComponent<Animator>();
    }
}


public void PlayAnimation()
{
    rangeBtnAnim.Play("RangeSelectionButton_Pressed");
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would simply use this setup with [Parameters](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AnimationParameters.html)

[image]

Make the `PressedAnimation` clip **not** `Loop Time` and use a `bool` parameter e.g. `IsPressed`. (One could also use triggers instead but in this case a bool is easier and saver - triggers stack ...)

Than the setup for the transitions:

Idle -> PressedAnimation

[image]

and PressedAnimation -> Idle

[image]

Than in your code instead you would set

```
rangeBtnAnim.SetBool("IsPressed", true);
```

or

```
rangeBtnAnim.SetBool("IsPressed", false);
```

to go back to idle.

**Note** the simplest way in fact of having animations (if they are not complex) would be to simply only have **1** single keyframe in `Idle` and also in `PRessedAnimation`. Unity would than simply make a transition animation interpolating between the values according to the transition duration settings.

---

Alternatively if your animations get more complex you would probably rather do something like

[image]

And for the two transitions
PressedAnimation -> StayPRessed
UnPressAnimation -> Idle
use the `ExitTime`

[image]

for the other two use the parameter

[image]

and

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for taking so much efforts to explain me in detail. i am redoing everything .soon update you on this. thanks again

Comment: this solution works for another button.only the problem with range selection buttons is - on click i am reloading the scene thus it returns to idle state by default.

Comment: than you should save the bool value `isPressed` elsewhere and when reloading the scene do somthing like `private void OnEnable(){ if(isPressed) { rangeBtnAnim.SetBool("IsPressed", true); }  }` to make sure it gets the correct value set after reloading

Answer (score 1):

Something I used in my games. Let's say you have two animations: Idle and Animated.
You want your button, after Animated finishes, to stays on the last frame right ? Then you create a third animation, Animated_Remains, which contains only one frame, the last from Animated.

Then, in your Animation Controller, you put a transition between Animated (no loop) and Animated_Remains (looped). If you want the same behaviour when transiting from Animated to Idle, then you create a 4th anim, Idle_Remains.

So, after clicking on your button, it will play the Animated animation, and automatically transit to the Animated_Remains.

I did that when I had to move my Camera with an animation and make it stay at the last frame position.

Comment: thank you so much . i will try this and update you soon.i was struggling for quite a long time

Comment: i have added screenshot to my question . i have created transition to hold animation (with loop checked) but still returning to idle state. i am calling `RangeSelectionButton_Pressed` on button click .can you please tell whats wrong please?

Comment: or you simply make the animation clip not `Loop` so it will anyway stay on the last keyframe of the animation